# Alfresco from sdk 2.2.0 to sdk3.0.1

Tags: alfresco

Is it possible to convert an alfresco AIO project, built with sdk 2.2.0,  to a new alfresco AIO project with sdk 3.0.1
The architecture is different:
- sdk 2.2.0 => 6 Maven modules
- sdk 3.0.1 => 3 Maven modules

I know that the xxx-repo-amp /src/main/amp/config/... files (2.2.0) move to xxx-platform-jar/src/main/resources/alfresco/... folders

But, for example where move the xxx-repo-amp /src/main/amp/WEB/ files ?

Thank you for your help !
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can upgrade your project structure from SDK 2.2.0 to SDK 3.0.1. I have done this many times and I know it works.

You should be able to generate a "test" project from the all-in-one template and that will help you see how to map the files.

To answer your question, src/main/amp/config/alfresco goes to src/main/resources/alfresco.

The web directory can go to src/main/resources/META-INF/resources OR it can go in src/main/assembly/web. Look at the README.md file that is created by default in that directory for a description of what should go in there.

Be sure to take a look at [compatibility](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/sdk-whats-new.html#sdk-whats-new__2) to understand whether or not SDK 3.0.1 will work with your version of Alfresco.