# Alfresco Context initialization failed : NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, alfresco

After migrating an alfresco project from sdk 2.2.0 to sdk 3.0.1, 
([Alfresco from sdk 2.2.0 to sdk3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47811077/alfresco-from-sdk-2-2-0-to-sdk3-0-1/47829801?noredirect=1#comment82631182_47829801))

I have the following issue when i run, by eclipse, clean install alfresco:run.

```
2017-12-15 15:05:19,809 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL 'jdbc:h2:C:\Users\jerome\eclipse\soludoc\klinck\klinck/alf_data_dev/h2_data/alf_dev;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;MVCC=FALSE;LOCK_MODE=0' with user 'alfresco'.
2017-12-15 15:05:19,811 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Connected to database H2 version 1.4.190 (2015-10-11)
2017-12-15 15:05:23,780 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
2017-12-15 15:05:23,780 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.1-metadata-query-indexes
2017-12-15 15:05:23,781 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.2-remove-jbpm-tables-from-db
2017-12-15 15:05:28,923 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2017-12-15 15:05:29,071 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
2017-12-15 15:05:31,043 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ca/uhn/hl7v2/HL7Exception
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:872)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 30 more
2017-12-15 15:05:31,394 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [localhost-startStop-1] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiEngineInitializer.onShutdown(ActivitiEngineInitializer.java:65)
    at org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.AbstractLifecycleBean.onApplicationEvent(AbstractLifecycleBean.java:67)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEventInternal(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:214)
    at org.alfresco.repo.management.SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SafeApplicationEventMulticaster.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-12-15 15:05:31,394 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [localhost-startStop-1] Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Dec 15 15:05:16 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:586)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-12-15 15:05:32,086 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Stopping 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2017-12-15 15:05:32,086 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Stopped 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2017-12-15 15:22:09,156 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Using database URL 'jdbc:h2:C:\Users\jerome\eclipse\soludoc\klinck\klinck/alf_data_dev/h2_data/alf_dev;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;MVCC=FALSE;LOCK_MODE=0' with user 'alfresco'.
2017-12-15 15:22:09,157 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.admin] [localhost-startStop-1] Connected to database H2 version 1.4.190 (2015-10-11)
2017-12-15 15:22:12,871 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V4.2-metadata-query-indexes
2017-12-15 15:22:12,871 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.1-metadata-query-indexes
2017-12-15 15:22:12,871 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.domain.schema.SchemaBootstrap] [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring script patch (post-Hibernate): patch.db-V5.2-remove-jbpm-tables-from-db
2017-12-15 15:22:18,177 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1]
2017-12-15 15:22:18,320 INFO  [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed, alfrescoNtlm1] complete
2017-12-15 15:22:20,215 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ca/uhn/hl7v2/HL7Exception
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:872)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 30 more
```

I have deleted .m2/repository folder and I have deleted alf_data_dev folder but I have the same issue.

I have no error in my source code and I can access the HL7Exception....

update (20171218) :

Yes it is in my POM :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>hapi-base</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>hapi-structures-v251</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I had not this issue with sdk 2.2

It's why I don't understand.....

clean install command is ok but alfresco:run command shows this error

It happens when the embedded Tomcat starts ::

[image]

During some tests, I have noticed that the jars, corresponding to the dependencies added in the platform-jar POM, have not been created when I build the project.
I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This mean you are missing at least one dependency in your pom , a dependency containing ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception
If you're sure you have all required dependencies on board, make sure that only dependencies from alfresco itself or tomcat are marked as provided in their scope.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building an AMP or a JAR? You are using third-party libraries, so make sure you are building an AMP instead. (No one should ever be building JARs for Alfresco, IMO).

Unfortunately, starting with SDK 3.0.0 or 3.0.1 the default is to build JARs.

Look in your pom.xml for the Maven Assembly Plugin that calls build-amp-file. By default it is commented out. Uncomment it to build AMPs.

Answer (score 0):

Found :

When adding dependencies to your project, make sure you place the dependencies in the platform pom file, as well as the main project pom file (depending on your project setup you might have to put the dependencies in both the dependencies section and the dependencyManagement section of the main project pom file).